# React Native BatchedBridge error

Tags: react-native

Whenever I move initialization code out of `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` and into an `app/index.js` file I get the following error

`Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly` I'm using yarn and wasn't getting this issue w/ npm. When I move code back to original files everything works fine again.

I've also tried removing yarn from my project uninstalling yarn `npm uninstall -g yarn` doesn't work.

I've done `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and set up connection to my computer in dev settings.

Not sure what's causing the issue.